# How to use insertion sorting on an array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, object

I have a Movie class set up and I am trying to create a function to sort an array of movies by release date and then by rating. I have 7 movies in a text document getting stored into my array and getter functions at the ready but I am having trouble converting what little I know about sorting an array of ints into an array where I need to sort strings and then doubles.

Here is my code:

---

```
string Movie::getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

double Movie::getRating() {
    return rating;
}

void sortByDateRating(Movie movies[], int SIZE) {
   int i;
   int j;
   int temp;      

   for (i = 1; i < SIZE; ++i) {
      j = i;
      
      while (j > 0 && movies[j] < movies[j - 1]) {

         
         temp = movies[j];
         movies[j] = movies[j - 1];
         movies[j - 1] = temp;
         --j;
      }
   }
}
```

---

I plan to call this function from a switch case I have in main. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Your sort code looks more like a bubble sort than an insert sort.  An insert sort starts a the beginning and searches for a good place to insert.  All the elements are shifted down by one (to make room for new data), then the data is inserted into the array.  Your code isn't doing this.

Comment: Looks like the Wikipedia description also uses swapping.  Maybe my definition is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really want to implement the sorting yourself, you can use the STL container [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or the equivalent container from [Boost](https://www.boost.org/).

Comment: Or just `std::sort` the array...

Comment: I would preferably like to sort it myself but thank you